# Promise q.allSettled to q.reduce

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a piece of code that uses the q promise library like this:

```
var q = require('q')
var promises = [ promise1, promise2, promise3]
q.allSettled(promises)
    .then( function(results) {
        for( var i=0; i<results.length; ++i ) { 
           if( results[i].state = 'fulfilled' ) { //do Something on success}
           else{ //do something on failure}
        }
})
```

This executes all the promises in parallel. How can I convert this to sequential execution? 
I did look around [Q Documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and the suggestion was to use `[].reduce` for sequential execution. I tried using the same but without much luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with reduce?

Comment: Please show us the (failed) attempt with `reduce`, not the working `allSettled` code.

Comment: For sequential execution, you have to *call the functions* that produce `promiseN`s sequentially, if you already have 3 promises around there's nothing you can do. So please show us that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "executing promises". Promises are a proxy for the *result* of asynchronous operations. Executing a promise is similar to executing the number 5.

What you *can* execute synchronously is functions returning promises. This is what `reduce` can do.

You can use a `.reflect` primitive instead of `allSettled`:

```
var functions = [promiseReturningFn1, promiseReturningFn2, promiseReturningFn3];
functions.reduce((soFar, current) => {
  return soFar.then(() => // wait for previous actions
    return current().reflect();
  });
}, Q());
```

And building `.reflect()` since Q doesn't have it:

```
Q.prototype.reflect = function() {
    var p = this;
    return p.then(v => ({ state: "fulfilled", value: v }),
            .catch(r => ({ state: "rejected", reason: r }));
}
```

This will run all actions sequentially but will continue running them on errors.

Comment: there were two things I was missing here - the first I wasn't calling the promise returning themselves sequentially. the second is the reflect() implementation. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my example here. It might be helpful.

We have a number 10 and we want to consistently subtract the numbers 2, 1, 3.

So the result should be 8, 7, 4.

```js
import Q from 'q';

let sum = 10;
const nums = [2, 1, 3];

const generatePromise = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            sum -= num
            console.log('sum', sum);
            resolve(sum);
        });
    })
}

// let's create an array of our promises
const promises = [];
nums.forEach(num => promises.push(generatePromise(num)));

// let's use Q.all to get the result
await Q.all(promises).then(data => console.log(data)); // [ 8, 7, 4 ]
```

It worked as expected!

But what if the execution time will be different?

```js
const generatePromise = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            sum -= num
            resolve(sum);
        }, 1000 * num); // <----- let's wait 2 sec for the first promise, 1 sec for the second one, and 3 sec for the last one
    })
}
```

Now we have a wrong result - [ 7, 9, 4 ]

How to solve it? this is a solution:

```js
let sum = 10;
const nums = [2, 1, 3];

const generatePromise = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            sum -= num
            console.log('sum', sum);
            resolve(sum);
        }, 1000 * num);
    })
}

nums.reduce(async (previousPromise, num) => {
    await previousPromise;
    return generatePromise(num);
}, Promise.resolve());
```